# Django кнопка выбрать список файлов/папок

Tags: django

У меня есть программа на python, которая делает логику из имен подпапок. Я перевожу данную программу на Django.
Мне надо в Django сделать кнопку выбора папки, после выбора необходимо получить имена подпапок. Есть ощущение, что для web приложения нет такого разрешения. Может как вариант, сделать кнопку, которая дает возможность выбрать сразу несколько папок, но тоже не знаю как это можно сделать?

Comment: Это по части `HTML/CSS/JS`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40654704/django-directory-upload-get-sub-directory-names/40812464#40812464

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/file-uploads/#uploading-multiple-files